# bootstrap and fontawesome icons not displaying on a page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fontawesome-4.4.0

In my view I have this code:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ErorMessage))
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h4 class="text-danger">An error occured while attempting to update this record</h4>
                    <i class="pull-left fa-exclamation-triangle fa-lg"></i>
                    <p class="text-danger">@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.ErorMessage)</p>
                </div>
            }
```

The icon won't display.  I get some weird square.  I've tried it with bootstrap glyphicons and fontawesome, but neither will work yet I have a left hand menu that uses fontawesome and the icons show correctly. Am I missing something here?

Comment: check the version of font awesome that you have added in your project.

Comment: its version 4.7

Answer (score 0):

One class is missing in your code. Please try:
`<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-lg"></i>`

The class `fa` also needs to be mentioned in the i attribute.

Comment: <i class="pull-left fa-exclamation-triangle fa-lg"></i>

Comment: The fa class is still missing in your example. Please review class by class. Only "fa" not "fa-"

Comment: youre right, I missed that, thank you, it works now :-)